# Word or phrase for 'Past glory'

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any word to describe past glory? Mostly elders use this to grumble and complain about the present. 
Example:

> "In those days, I used to run 4 miles daily. Now walking a quarter mile is a task."
>
> "In our days people helped and took care of neighbors and relatives without much ado. Nowadays even taking care of your own parents has become a great sacrifice. Where the world is going!"

Maybe the splendor of the past is exaggerated. But the point is the past was wonderful, when the present is harsh. In such a situation, what is the word for the past splendor?

Answer (score 2):

Halcyon comes to mind: see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halcyon)

> 1a : characterized by happiness, great success, and prosperity : golden —often used to describe an idyllic time in the past that is remembered as better than today the halcyon days of youth

*Sample Usage*: 
[Economic Recovery: Lessons from the Post-World War II Period](https://www.mercatus.org/publication/economic-recovery-lessons-post-world-war-ii-period)

> The hardships of the previous fifteen years of war and depression were replaced by rising living standards, increased opportunities, and a newly emerging American culture confident of its future and place in the world. It is not surprising that politicians of all stripes harken back to **those halcyon days** to make a case for their agendas.
>   (*emphasis mine*)

Comment: I think your answer could be strengthened by giving an example of how one would use it in a sentence.  It's true that the OP should have included a sample sentence -- but it's not too late to do that, with your word in its appropriate place!